# Problema com malloc

Tags: c, ponteiro, array

Galera, to fazendo um pequeno programinha que dado um numero qualquer, entra em uma função que divide o numero em um vetor e retorna o numero de casas decimais(numero de posições) que o vetor tem. Em todos os guias e tutoriais que vejo diz que o modo que eu estou fazendo esta certo, mas por algum motivo o codigo não esta funcionando.
Eis o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int verPal(int num1, int *v);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *v;
    int numero, y;
    printf("digite o numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    y = verPal(numero,v);
    for (int i = 0; i<y; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d \n", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int verPal(int num1, int *v){
    int x=num1;
    int y=0;

    while(x != 0){
        x = x/10;
        y = y+1;
    }
    x = num1;
    v = (int *) malloc(y*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; x != 0; i=i+1) {
        v[i] = x%10;
        x = x/10;
    }
    return y;
}
```

A ideia aqui no caso seria, por exemplo, entra `numero = 10`, `y` retorna 2 e eu tenho um vetor com 2 posições sendo elas `v[0] = 0` e `v[1] = 1`. Quando eu faço `malloc(y*sizeof(int))` que deveria ser, no caso, 2*o tamanho de um inteiro, ele n me retorna 2 espaços, apenas 1, como posso resolver isso? To fazendo algo errado?
Obrigado

Comment: Não é só este problema, esse código não funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int verPal(int num1, int *v)`

```
// no main:
y = verPal(numero,v);
```

A função `verPal` recebe uma cópia do apontador `v` fornecido pelo `main` e atribui a essa cópia local o endereço retornado por `malloc`, logo o `v` como visto na função `main` não aponta para o valor alocado por `malloc`.

`v` como visto no `main` deve continuar sendo um apontador para `int` (ou seja, `int*`) porém a função `verPal` deve receber o endereço de `v` para que as alterações que ela faz no `v` sejam visíveis fora da função.

Aqui está o código revisado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int verPal(int num1, int **v); // <--- verPal recebe o endereço de um apontador
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int *v; // <--- v continua sendo um apontador para int
    int numero, y;
    printf("digite o numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    y = verPal(numero,&v); // <--- passe o endereço de v
    for (int i = 0; i<y; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d \n", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int verPal(int num1, int **v){ // <--- verPal recebe o endereço de um apontador
    int x=num1;
    int y=0;

    while(x != 0){
        x = x/10;
        y = y+1;
    }
    x = num1;
    int *vi = (int *) malloc(y*sizeof(int)); // <--- apontador local recebe retorno de malloc
    for (int i = 0; x != 0; i=i+1) {
        vi[i] = x%10; // <--- alterar valor no espaço alocado usando apontador local
        x = x/10;
    }
    *v = vi; // <--- apontador fora dessa função é atualizado com endereço novo
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Acho que meu conceito de ponteiros está meio defaso asuhsau, anyway, obrigado cara, ajudou muito aqui :3

Answer (score 0):

Andei analisando seu codigo e sua lógica parece certa, porém percebi alguns problemas, o vetor v é redimensionado na função verPal, **porém ele não é devolvido para main**. Assim voce tenta sem sucesso imprimi-lo na main.

Algumas das soluções para este problema seriam:

Utilizar o vetor v como variavél global. Declarando-o fora da int main e fora da função.

Ou imprimir o conteudo do vetor dentro da função, sem retornar nada para int main.

Veja minhas alterações: Variavél global.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int *v;
int verPal(int num1);
int main() {
    int numero, y,i;
    printf("digite o numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    y = verPal(numero);
    for (i = 0; i<y; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d \n", v[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
int verPal(int num1){
    int x=num1;
    int y=0,i;

    while(x != 0){
        x = x/10;
        y = y+1;
    }
    x = num1;
    v = (int*) malloc((y)*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; x != 0; i=i+1) {
        v[i] = x%10;
        x = x/10;
    }
 return y;
}
```

Outra maneira, imprimindo o vetor na função:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void verPal(int num1);
int main() {
    int numero, y,i;
    printf("digite o numero");
    scanf("%d", &numero);
    verPal(numero);
    return 0;
}
void verPal(int num1){
    int x=num1;
    int y=0,i;
    int *v;
    while(x != 0){
        x = x/10;
        y = y+1;
    }
    x = num1;
    v = (int*) malloc((y)*sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; x != 0; i=i+1) {
        v[i] = x%10;
        x = x/10;
    }
    for (i = 0; i<y; i = i+1) {
        printf("%d \n", v[i]);
    }
}
```

Lembrando que existem outras maneiras de corrigir, como por exemplo, devolver o vetor para main, porém acredito que teriamos que fazer mais mudanças no seu código.

Outra observação: numeros muito grandes (que excedem o tamanho de um int, darão problema. Ex: 12345678912, este numero não é um input válido.

Espero que tenha ajudado.